# mongoDB lookups upto 4-5 levels with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am trying to create aggregate code which can join multiple collections and fetches data based on the condition

My collections looks like the following

**Users Collection(Example Document)**

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"6137038058d4632824c84872"},
"first_name":"test",
"last_name":".",
"email":"valid@gmail.com",
"enrolled_courses":[
  {
    "completed_lessons":[],
    "completed":false,
    "_id": {"$oid":"6142d1c76d657428903420db"},
    "course_id":{"$oid":"614033510a61aa1f3c8b94ff"}
  },
  {
    "completed_lessons":[],
    "completed":false,
    "_id":{"$oid":"6156d686dcbc58503c7ec679"},
    "course_id":{"$oid":"61486e57460b5a422c6e63ca"}
  },
  {
    "completed_lessons":["616d181e62cb265db07d9273","616d182e62cb265db07d9293"],
    "completed":false,
    "_id":{"$oid":"616d2424149936380c186c2d"},
    "course_id":{"$oid":"616d105662cb265db07d91cf"}
  }
 ]
}
```

**Courses Collection(Example Document)**

```
{
 "_id":{"$oid":"6135f735b399f03ba03d74ce"},
 "type":1,
 "enrolled_users":["61374040c27237b1ed87480b"],
 "is_deleted":0,
 "status":1,
 "company_id":{"$oid":"6135f6c9b399f03ba03d74a0"},
 "course":"Course 1"
}
```

**Modules Collection(Example Document)**

```
{
 "_id":{"$oid":"616d17fd62cb265db07d9240"},
 "type":1,
 "is_always_available":false,
 "is_deleted":0,
 "status":1,
 "company_id":{"$oid":"6135f6c9b399f03ba03d74a0"},
 "course_id":{"$oid":"616d105662cb265db07d91cf"},
 "module_name":"module 3",
 "due_date":{"$date":"2021-10-18T00:00:00.000Z"}
}
```

**Lessons Collection(Example Document)**

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"616d184962cb265db07d92cb"},
  "lessson_image":null,
  "status":1,
  "is_deleted": 0,
  "module_id":{"$oid":"616d17e462cb265db07d921f"},
  "lessson_name":"Lesson 3"
}
```

I want to fetch details of all the **courses** user have enrolled and fetch all course's modules and its lessons

My expected output should be like following -

```
[
{
    //CourseDetail 1 Keys,
    modules: [
        {
            //Module Details
            lessons: [{
                //lessons of this module
            }]
        },
        {
            //Module Details
            lessons: [{
                //lessons of this module
            }]
        }
    ]
},
{
    //CourseDetail 2 Keys,
    modules: [
        {
            //Module Details
            lessons: [{
                //lessons of this module
            }]
        },
        {
            //Module Details
            lessons: [{
                //lessons of this module
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

My current query is following,  what it currently does is it groups the modules and its lessons together and bind it to single course object. The fetching of modules and lessons is perfect as per my requirement but course array contains only 1 single object and it holds list of all the modules from other courses also.

**Current Query Code**

```
let courseDetails = await users.aggregate([
{
    $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id), }
},
{$unwind:"$enrolled_courses"},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'courses',
        localField: "enrolled_courses.course_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "courseDetails"
    }
},
{ $unwind: { path: "$courseDetails", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "modules",
        let: { currentCourseId: "$courseDetails._id"},
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$course_id", "$$currentCourseId"]},
                        { $eq: ["$status", 1]},
                        { $eq: ["$is_deleted", 0]},
                        {
                            $or: [
                                { $eq: ["$is_always_available", true] },
                                { $gte: ["$due_date", convertedDate]}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            module_name: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            course_id: 1
        }
    }],
        as: "moduleList"
    }
},
{ $unwind: { path: "$moduleList", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "lessons",
        let: { curentModuleId: "$moduleList._id"},
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        { $eq: ["$status", 1] },
                        { $eq: ["$is_deleted", 0]},
                        { $eq: ["$module_id", "$$curentModuleId"]}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                lessson_name: 1,
                module_id: 1
            }
        }],
        as: "moduleList.lessons"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
            
        _id: "$_id",
        course_id: { $first: "$enrolled_courses.course_id"},
        course_name: { $first: "$courseDetails.course"},
        completed_lessons: { $first: "$enrolled_courses.completed_lessons"},
        current_lessons: { $first: "$enrolled_courses.current_lessons"},
        completed: { $first: "$enrolled_courses.completed"},
        enrolled_users_count: {
            $first: "$courseDetails.enrolled_users"
        },
        modules: {
            $push: "$moduleList"
            }        
        }
},
{
    $project: {
        course_id: 1,
        course_name: 1,
        completed_lessons: 1,
        current_lessons: 1,
        completed: 1,
        enrolled_users_count: {
            $size: "$enrolled_users_count"
        },
        modules: 1        
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        course_id: { $first: "$course_id"},
        course_name: { $first: "$course_name"},
        completed_lessons: { $first: "$completed_lessons"},
        current_lessons: { $first: "$current_lessons"},
        completed: { $first: "$completed"},
        enrolled_users_count: { $first: "$enrolled_users_count"},
        modules: { $first: "$modules"}
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Four collections - this looks more like an relational database design. Usually the number of collections is much less than the number of tables in according relational database. Without knowing any details, I would assume Courses, Modules and Lessons all are modeled in one collection only.

Comment: According to the functionality, we have large number of lessons that are associated with particular module and large number of modules associated to particular course. I created multiple collections for this is because we can manage all of this individually as well. So, I just want to fetch all the user courses(available in enrolled_courses of users collection) and all its modules and its lessons in one go.

Comment: if you can simplify the data, remove extra fields keep like only 1, instead of ids use numbers, and check the ids to exists to the other collections. Its already so many look-ups. I think you should try nested lookups, like lookup with pipeline that has other lookup with pipeline inside